# Probability of 11 members in a group of 12 choose the same outcome.

Tags: probability

**Example**: Suppose there's an election and three candidates are running for the presidency. What are the odds that 11 people out of 12 will choose the same candidate? (assuming each person has a 1/3 chance to pick either candidate).

**Attempt**: I think that there are 3^12 possible outcomes, (3 alternatives, 12 subjects that will choose the alternatives) and 12 desirable outcomes for each candidate, so 36 overall. So my guess is 36/3^11.

Comment: "Tries" is not "probability" is not "odds."  Please re-write your question more carefully.

Comment: I removed the last bit about tries. The probability then is approximately  0.02%, correct ?

Comment: I don't understand your $36$ at all ... '12 desirable outcomes for each candidate'?  can you explain that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the candidates $A$, $B$, and $C$.  The probability you get the outcome $A = 11$, $B = 1$ and $C=0$ is given by the trinomial distribution, which here is:

$$P(A=11, B=1, C=0) = {12! \over 11! 1! 0!} (1/3)^{11} (1/3)^1 (1/3)^0$$.

But you can get the criterion output if $A=1$, $B=11$, $C=0$... and likewise for other permutations.  There are $3!=6$ such permutations, and you must add up their probabilities.

Thus:

$$3! {12! \over 11! 1! 0!} (1/3)^{11} (1/3)^1 (1/3)^0 = \frac{8}{59049} \approx 0.000135481.$$

Comment: Thank you, this makes perfect sense. I was having trouble with the permutations of the desirable/criterion output.

Comment: Permutations:  $A=11,B=1,C=0$... $A=11,B=0,C=1$... $A=1,B=11,C=0$... [can you fill in the rest of the six?]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you calculated the odds and not the probability.

When counting successful outcomes, there are $12$ ways to get $11$ the same for each of $3$ candidates and for each of those the one different outcome can be one of two, hence:

$$P(11\ \text{same}) = \frac{12\cdot 3\cdot 2}{3^{12}} = .00013548$$